# How to center align columns of different lengths using numpy.savetxt in Python?

Tags: python, format, alignment, output

I have several lists that contain both strings and floats as their elements.

```
import numpy as num

COLUMN_1 = ['KIC 7742534', 'Variable Star of RR Lyr type' , 'V* V368 Lyr',
        'KIC 7742534', '4.0', '0.4564816']

COLUMN_2 = ['KIC 76', 'Variable Star' , 'V* V33 Lyr',
        'KIC 76', '5.0', '0.45']

DAT = num.column_stack((COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2))
num.savetxt('SAVETXT.txt', DAT, delimiter=' ', fmt='{:^10}'.format('%s'))
```

The output I get when running this file is the following:

```
KIC 7742534    ,    KIC 76    
Variable Star of RR Lyr type    ,    Variable Star    
V* V368 Lyr    ,    V* V33 Lyr    
KIC 7742534    ,    KIC 76    
4.0    ,    5.0    
0.4564816    ,    0.45
```

The ideal output would look like this (including an aligned header)

```
#ELEMENT1                            ELEMENT2
KIC 7742534                     ,    KIC 76    
Variable Star of RR Lyr type    ,    Variable Star    
V* V368 Lyr                     ,    V* V33 Lyr    
KIC 7742534                     ,    KIC 76    
4.0                             ,    5.0    
0.4564816                       ,    0.45
```

How could I get an output like this (with aligned header), if the strings don't have a max width defined. I have tried modifying the format of the strings (fmt), but no luck so far.

-Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to calculate the maximum string length of of the longest row of your output (or input depending on how you look at it), which a method similar to

```
max_len = max(max(map(len,l)) for l in zip(COLUMN_1,COLUMN_2))
```

Will achieve. After that you need to change the `fmt` parameters dynamically based on the value of max_len which you can do like so:

`fmt=('{:^%d}' % max_len).format('%s')`

The following non-numpy example shows the expected output:

```
with open('ofile.txt','w+') as f:
    max_len = max(max(map(len,l)) for l in zip(COLUMN_1,COLUMN_2))
    for line in zip(COLUMN_1,COLUMN_2):
        f.write(','.join(('{:<%s}' % (max_len)).format(e) for e in line)+'\n')
```

Produces a text file `ofile.txt` containing:

```
KIC 7742534                 ,KIC 76                      
Variable Star of RR Lyr type,Variable Star               
V* V368 Lyr                 ,V* V33 Lyr                  
KIC 7742534                 ,KIC 76                      
4.0                         ,5.0                         
0.4564816                   ,0.45
```

Comment: You don't need to manually chain formatting methods together like this; just use nested formats. For example, `'{1:^{0}}'.format('%s', max_len)`. And even if you _do_ want to manually chain them, why alternate between `%`-formatting and `{}`-formatting like this? (This is really more a question for the OP than the answerer, since you're just following his example. But you did take it one step farther, alternating yet again, so…)